# what is bottom technical principles of websphere MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

what is bottom technical principles of IBM M Q Series? what is it's encapsulation? socket?Message Queue(Inter-Process Communication)? or what?  some people know about that? help....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere MQ uses an IBM proprietary wire protocol which is not publicly documented.  However, it runs over TCP/IP, and can be inspected by a Wireshark filter for both WMQ v6 and v7.

There's a protocol for use by low-bandwidth telemetry devices to talk to MQ called MQTT which is also proprietary but is documented by IBM [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-mqtt/index.html).

In the mainframe world the protocol rides on VTAM/APPC.